# What parameters are sensitive to change in a Chainlink VRF consumer contract?

Tags: chainlink

The [Chainlink VRF documentation section](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/) is a bit meager as of today, I was wondering whether there is any merit for smart contract developers to allow for Chainlink VRF consumer contracts configuration parameters to change in the future, such as the LINK fee (due to the VRF oracle).

*P.S. I was asked by the Chainlink team to turn this doubt into a stackoverflow thread*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parameters like VRFCoordinator contract and public key of the VRF node won't change often, if at all with the current version of VRF.

Take note though that in an upcoming improved version, there will be more flexibility, which will include dynamic VRF costs based on gas in the response etc

Comment: You mention that even the VRF coordinator contract (and its key hash commitment) can change, but in your own solidity SDK that variable is private and immutable: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/3b9158dbdd346c6884a2496731092248534857b9/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol#L183

Also, what about fees in V1, I assume that they can indeed change, if so, who determines them?

Finally, when VRF v2 is released will v1 still be supported?

Comment: if you want to future proof your smart contract, then yes you should make all those variables in a way where they can be updated by an authorized account. For fees in v1, they will most likely be staying what they are now until v2 comes out, they are set by nodes. Once VRF v2 comes out, v1 will most likely be supported for a while, but all users will be encouraged to upgrade to vrf v2 due to the numerous clear advantages it will have

Comment: Is the VRF payload always 32-bytes in length?
As in, no tiny numbers (e.g. 0x000...0001) are possibly sent back by the oracles?

Comment: @lepidotteri yes the payload is always a large number approx 32 bytes. Take note if you need a smaller number, you can do a modulus operation to always get a number between 1 and x